# Drools rules in xtext format

Tags: java, drools, xtext

I am new to Xtext and I want to use it to generate some code for drools rules. I have the following problem, I don't know how to write the dialect to have that `$order` in front of a Order(). I would really appreciate if someone will show me how to handle this example.

This is what I have tried so far

```
Model:
    declarations+=Declaration*;
    
Declaration:
    Rule;

State:
    name=ID
;


    Rule:
        'rule' ruleDescription=STRING
        '@specification'specificationDescription=STRING
        'ruleflow-group' ruleflowDescription=STRING
            'when' when=[State|QualifiedName]
            'then' then=[State|QualifiedName];
    
    QualifiedName: ID ('.' ID)*;
    DolarSign: ('$' ID)*;
```

And here is the code for the rule:

```
    rule "apply 10% discount to all items over US$ 100,00 in an order"
    @specification "101"
    ruleflow-group "All"
    when
        $order : Order(appliedBefore == null)
                 Order($name : /customer/name) from $order
        $item  : OrderItem( value > 100 ) from $order.items
    then
        System.out.println("10% applied" + $name);
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply use:

```
'when $' when=[State|QualifiedName]
```

Comment: No, I don't want to highlight the "$" in the when block for Drools. Also there can be more than one variables in when block, for example: when $A :A(..) $B:B(..)

Comment: I think you have to create a custom terminal that starts with "$" and crossreferences to a State through its ID.
As for the multiplicity I guess you will have to create an intermediary rule that acts as the container, a bit like this (long time since I've done some Xtext):
`Rule: (...) 'when' when=WhenStatement*
WhenStatement= StateReference ':' WhenStatementBody
StateReference: '$' referencedState=[State|QualifiedName]
WhenStatementBody: ...`